# Is there a reason why the CSS "clear: both" doesn't work for <a> tags?

Tags: html, css

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rc5J8/451/) The div with id `parent` is not being scaled to the appropriate height. This is fixed when the last element in the parent div with the class `c_b` is styled with `clear:both`. However, if ONLY the `<a>` tag with the class `link` is styled with `clear:both` nothing happens. I am wondering why `clear:both` appears to work correctly if the last element is a div but doesn't work for link elements.

Thanks

Comment: <a> is an inline element, you need to add display: block in order to get same behaviour

Comment: [relevant spec link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is an inline tag and a div is a block.

add `display: block` as css to the `a` tag.

**edit:**
Since this is getting some upvotes here's how to add the css:

Add the css as `style` in the `a` tag:
`<a href="#yourlink" style="display: block;"> My link </a>`

Or by adding it to a stylesheet linked from the `<head>` tag.